# Prove the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality (missing a step)

Tags: vector-spaces

during lecture notes I only caught most of the proof and couldnt write a step down fast enough, and I'm having a touch trouble seeing how to get from the previous step to the next.
Here is what i have written down..

Proof in $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$
( |u . v| = |u \cdot v|)$

assume $|u \cdot v|^2 \leq ||u||^2 ||v||^2$

$0 \leq ||u||^2 ||v||^2 - |u \cdot v|^2$

$0 \leq (u_1^2 + u_2^2)(v_1^2+v_2^2) - (u_1v_1+u_2v_2)^2$

$0 \leq$ ..................... (this is what I'm missing) ????

$|u . v|^2 \leq ||u||^2 ||v||^2$  (then he wrote something about order preserving functions)

I tried expanding the preceeding to the missing line but couldn't get it, I think I have to replace something with a formula somewhere... can someone please fill in this spot for me?

Comment: Expanding the right hand side of the preceding line should be exactly what gets you to the next. That, and cancelling stuff like $u_1^2v_1^2 - u_1^2 v_1^2$ that appears when you expand.

Comment: but i ended up getting 0 <= u1^2v1^2 + u2^2v1^2 - 2(u1u2v1v2)

How do I reduce that to |u . v|^2 <= ||u||^2 ||v||^2 ?

Comment: Note that the proof is written up backwards (one often does that to find a proof, but it's not so good to write up a proof that way). The first line is what you want to prove. But since the transition between any two consecutive lines is an equivalence, it is not totally wrong. Anyway, it goes $$0\leqslant \lVert u\rVert^2\lVert v\rVert^2 - \lvert u\cdot v\rvert^2 \iff \dotsc \iff 0 \leqslant u_1^2v_2^2 + u_2^2v_1^2 - 2u_1u_2v_1v_2,$$ and now you need to recognise the right hand side of that as $(u_1v_2 - u_2v_1)^2$, which you know is non-negative, since it's a square.

Comment: why was my question marked down =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0 \leqslant \lVert u\rVert^2 \lVert v\rVert^2 - \lvert u \cdot v\rvert^2$ if and only if

$0 \leqslant (u_1^2 + u_2^2)(v_1^2+v_2^2) - (u_1v_1+u_2v_2)^2$ if and only if

$0 \leqslant u_1^2v_2^2 + u_2^2v_1^2-2u_1v_1u_2v_2=(u_1v_2 - u_2v_1)^2$ which is true.

So the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality holds.

Comment: ok the part I can't see/follow is how in the third line, after the 0 <- part, the left side is equal to the right side. can you show me the algebraic steps or formulas you used to make sure that is true?

Comment: @JL Sorry, there is a typo. Should be minus sign. It's just complete square.

Comment: oh im starting to see it. but how exactly do we know "which is true" ? or rather, that 0 is less than or equal to it? just because we reduced it down?

Comment: @JL Cauchy we deduce that Schwartz inequality holds iff $(u_1v_2 - u_2v_1)^2\geq 0$.

Comment: but how is that actually proven?

Comment: @JL You mean why square is nonnegative? This fact can be proved using axiom of real number. I think you can assume it's correct.

Comment: no, i mean how does that last reduction actually prove what we wanted in the first place ie: |u . v|^2 <= ||u||^2 ||v||^2

Comment: @JL Because every step is an if and only if relation. If you know the last reduction is correct, following the steps backwards, you will get the inequality.

Comment: oh wait I see, I actually did mean why square is not negative, because thats another way of saying its >= 0

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what you wrote, but the proof can be easy and pretty short:

Let $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ be an indeterminate, and look at the equation:

$$0\le(xu+v)\cdot(xu+v)=x^2||u|^2+2x\,u\cdot v+||v||^2$$

The above is a non-negative quadratic in $\;x\;$ and thus its discriminant is non-positive:

$$\Delta=4u\cdot v-4||u||^2||v||^2\le 0$$

and this proves the CSB (Cauchy-Schwarz-Buniakovski) inequality